# Developing Telegram like application using GetStream.io

Tags: channel, getstream-io

For example, in Telegram, we have **channels** (private / public) and, their members can join and post into it. So, like that, I am trying to implement this feature using `GetStream` where :

- Member can create private and public channel.
- Member should have right to **join** any public channel.
- Member can get right to **post**, also.

  Can anyone, please, suggest how this can be implemented using `GetStream` ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The three points you mentioned are possible.

Most of that can be configured in the Stream Chat dashboard's [permissions](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/chat_permission_policies/) section for a given [channel type](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/channel_features/). (Image below)[image: Image shows stream chat dashboard permissions]

You can create channel types for private and public channels and set the permissions as desired (user can create private and public, user can post, etc).

For the second point (user can join any public channel), you can set the permissions so normal users can see the messages and interact with the channel, and if they want to join as a member, you can use the [invite API](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/channel_invites/) or [changing channel members API](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/channel_members/).

Comment: @harshita are you able to create public chat and join users without inviting? any thoughts and approach? pls help.